# Xorg PPA vs Michael Marley or Nouveau

Tags: drivers, ppa, nouveau, xorg-edgers

Which driver source is better Xorg vs Michael Marley or should I stick with Nouveau? Please explain your answer? My graphic card is MSI GTX 760 2GB TF IV GAMING OC
And what is the difference of this commands when installing Nvidia drivers from PPA sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-settings and sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 ?
Whe I use the Nvidia drivers I have the following problem in VLC should I worry about that?

> Blockquote

When I play the video there is no stuttering ,but when I move the mouse across the playing bar  (just moving no clicking there happens image stuttering

> Blockquote

Comment: be careful when adding video drivers related ppas though like xorg edgers if you run update and upgrade after you add it and then decide to remove the ppa it can destabilize the system.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know who Michael Marley is and what is his ppa.

Proprietary Nvidia drivers perform better in games than Nouveau in most cases.

You can install recommended drivers from Ubuntu repositories. They should work OK for your adapter.

This can be done from System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.

For very new adapters with Ubuntu 14.04 you may need newer driver than in official repository (331). In this case xorg-edgers may be useful.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~mamarley/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia

Comment: @MackJack It is not full. There are not all drivers. But packing may be OK. But xorg-edgers do it for a long time.